# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax t

Tags: mysql-error-1064

```
INSERT INTO `recipe`(`Recipe_Id`, `Recipe_Name`, `Ingredients`, `Method`, `Servings`, `Ranking`) VALUES ([1],['Garlic Chicken'],['4 cloves garlic, chopped','1/2 cup any oil','1/4 cup bread crumbs','4 boneless, skinless chicken breasts''salt as required','black pepper as required'],['(if you have oven Preheat oven to 375 degrees F (190 degrees C))In small pan, stir fry garlic with the oil then mix chicken with garlic and black pepper and add garlic mixture on it and then coat them with bread crumbs then  Bake in the preheated oven for 45 minutes to 1 hour. INCASE you donot have oven you can cook it in a sauce pan using 1 cup oil. cook untill it gets golden brown and then serve],[5],[0]);
```

I do not know where I am wrong. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing quotation mark after serve. You syntax for the ingredients values is also wrong. It should be:

```
INSERT  INTO recipe
        ( Recipe_Id ,
          Recipe_Name ,
          Ingredients ,
          Method ,
          Servings ,
          Ranking
        )
VALUES  ( 1 ,
          'Garlic Chicken' ,
          '4 cloves garlic, chopped, 1/2 cup any oil, 1/4 cup bread crumbs, 4 boneless, skinless chicken breasts salt as required,black pepper as required' ,
          '(if you have oven Preheat oven to 375 degrees F (190 degrees C))In small pan, stir fry garlic with the oil then mix chicken with garlic and black pepper and add garlic mixture on it and then coat them with bread crumbs then Bake in the preheated oven for 45 minutes to 1 hour. INCASE you donot have oven you can cook it in a sauce pan using 1 cup oil. cook untill it gets golden brown and then serve' ,
          5 ,
          0
        );
```